# Finding the curvature of a link belt going around a circular pully

Tags: python, math

So this is a super random question that will probably benefit from a whole bunch of screenshots.

I am trying to figure out a formula for a function that can generate the values that dictate the curvature of a link belt traveling around a circular pulley. In essence, imagine a straight line comprised of N samples that is being bent at some point around a circular curvature. The angle between the points on this line going around the arc will be less than 180 degrees, whereas all other points will form a straight line. I believe (but can't currently prove) that this problem can be broken down into some sort of well defined function, but I'm not quite sure how at the moment.

Here's some screenshots showing what I'm trying to figure out. The blue squares (and line) show a set of data points along a flat line which can be bent in 2D. The green squares (and line) show the effective angle between each point and the immediate neighboring points for the blue squares.

What I am trying to do is to figure out a function that generates the GREEN CURVE as shown in the screenshots. The green curve only appears to be based on two things: 1) the density of the samples (or squares) along the blue line, and the start and stop location of the bend itself (the distance between which essentially dictate the radius of curvature).

Screenshot #1: The blue line is bent at 180 degrees.

[image]

Screenshot #2: The blue line has been altered so that it is only bent at 45 degrees. Note that the profile of the green graph is essentially identical- only the amplitude has changed. This makes me believe that this problem is essentially independent from the actual radius of the curvature that the blue squares are being bent into.

[image]

Screenshot #3: Back to a 180 degree bend, but this time the start/end locations of the bend have been increased. The green graph has widened significantly as a result, presumably because the angle between the blue samples has decreased considerably.

[image]

Screenshot #4: The start/end locations of the bend have been brought together, creating a smaller bend. Note how the green graph has changed into a spike instead.

[image]

Screenshot #5: This is the same as #1, but I have *increased* the number of samples instead. This seems to affect the green curve much in the same way that increasing the radius of the bend does.

[image]

Screenshot #6: Here I have decreased the total number of samples, causing the green graph to turn spiky again.

[image]

Video #1: Here's a simple animation of the effects on the green graph of altering the radius of the bend in realtime as it moves from right to left:

[image]

Video #2: Here's another animation, but this time with a static bend radius and an altered number of samples instead:

[image]

So to recap, what I'm trying to do here is to design a function that takes four inputs: a starting location for a bend (along a 0 to 1 space- ie, 0 to 100%), an end location for the bend (ditto), the total number of samples along that line, and a sampling index (which determines which sample to retrieve the angle for).

What I'm trying to get out of this function is an angular value that determines the curvature of that sample- so essentially how bent it is in relationship to the previous and next samples along the bent line.

Is this possible to calculate somehow? It seems like it should be a fairly well defined function, but I can't seem to find anything like it online.

Comment: Are you asking for the mathematical representation of your observation (off-topic) or for the Python implementation of this equation? If the latter, please provide the formula and explain why you were not able to implement it.

Comment: Both, kinda- I'm most well versed in Python and I was looking to implement the algorithm using that language, so that's just what I'd marked down.

Comment: I am afraid asking for the mathematical representation is off-topic on SO. There are other stackexchange boards better equipped to provide an answer.